# ¿Cómo usar el metodo setItemWidget de QTreeWidget en python3 PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Mi duda es básicamente eso, como insertar un widget dentro de un `QTreeWidgetItem`, dentro del método `setItemWidget` tiene `params` que son los parámetros que desconozco a la hora de utilizar este método, soy relativamente nuevo en esto de python y pyqt5, estoy agradecido de cualquier ayuda que me puedan aportar

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QTreeWidget,QTreeWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        self.tree_widget = QTreeWidget()
        self.tree_widget.setHeaderHidden(True)


        child1 = QTreeWidgetItem(["child top level"])
        child2 = QTreeWidgetItem(["child"])

        child1.addChild(child2)
        self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItem(child1)

        item_widget = QWidget()
        self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(params)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.tree_widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyWidget()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46053590/15026532) en ingles te puede ayudar

Comment: Muchas Gracias, es lo que buscaba :')